# Images not loading and not displaying on HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, web2py

I am working on a website that, when loaded, it displays the compiled image from an HTML canvas element. My problem is that I can't tell when an image is loaded to draw it to the canvas or how to force an image to be loaded before I proceed to the next step. I have been looking through previous posts about the subject and have tried a lot of different solutions but nothing is working for me.

I am using web2py so I do use some Python helpers which are run on the server side.

When I use this:

```
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
context = canvas.getContext('2d');
image1 = new Image();
image1.src = '{{=URL('static', 'images/image-wrap-border-land.png')}}'; //resolves to: '/SNotes/static/images/image-wrap-border-land.png'
image1.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(image1, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
};
```

Since the image isn't loaded, the onload function doesn't do anything and it skips over it. I have also tried putting the onload function before I set the source but the image still isn't drawn.

I have tried:

```
//code from above
if(image1.completed) {
    context.drawImage(image1, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

But have faced the same problem.

I have also looked at the possibility that the image is producing an error as it is loaded. To catch this I wrote:

```
//code from above
image1.onerror = function() {
    console.log('error');
}
```

But the image source is fine, and the image isn't producing an error, it is just taking a long time to load.

Is there a way to wait for an image to load before it is drawn to the canvas?

---

Edit to add specificity:

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="profile-container" class="container-fluid">
    <h1>My Notes</h1>
    <div id="empty-orders" class="column-wrapper disable" style="padding-top: 5px; margin: 0 38%;">
        <h3>Create a Note and it will appear here</h3>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline">{{=A('GET STARTED', _href=URL('default', 'canvas_board_print'))}}</button>
    </div>
    <div id="loading" class="column-wrapper">
        <i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
    </div>
    <div id="row1" class="row">

    </div>
</div>
```

My javascript looks like this:

```
function showOrders(note_orders) {
    var orders = note_orders;
    //console.log(orders);
    var row_num = 1;
    var node_num = 1;
    if(orders.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i != orders.length; i++) {
            orders[i].border = JSON.parse(orders[i].border);
            orders[i].image_retouching = JSON.parse(orders[i].image_retouching);
            orders[i].shipping_info = JSON.parse(orders[i].shipping_info);
            var new_node = $("<div>", {id: "node" + node_num, "class": "col-xs-3 node-wrapper"});
            var new_canvas = $('<canvas>', {id: "canvas" + node_num, style: 'display: none'});
            var new_image = $('<img>', {id: "note_prev" + node_num, 'class': 'img-responsive'});
            $('#row' + row_num).append(new_node);
            $('#node'+ node_num).append(new_canvas).append(new_image).append(processOrders(orders[i], node_num));
            node_num++;
            if (i != 0 && (i + 1) % 4 == 0) {
                row_num++;
                var new_row = $("<div>", {id: "row" + row_num, "class": "row"});
                $(' #profile-container ').append(new_row);
            }
        }
        $(' #loading ').addClass('disable');
    } else {
        $(' #loading ').addClass('disable');
        $(' #empty-orders ').removeClass('disable');
    }
}
function processOrders(curr_order, node_num) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas' + node_num);
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var image1 = new Image();
    image1.src = curr_order.image_url;
    canvas.width = image1.naturalWidth;
    canvas.height = image1.naturalHeight;
    if(image1.complete) {
        context.drawImage(image1, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        if(curr_order.border.style == 'color_wrap') {
            document.getElementById('note_prev' + node_num).style.border = "10px solid " + curr_order.border.color;
        } else if(curr_order.border.style == 'image_wrap') {
            var image_wrap = new Image();
            if(canvas.width > canvas.height) {
                image_wrap.src = '{{=URL('static', 'images/image-wrap-border-land.png')}}';
            } else {
                image_wrap.src = '{{=URL('static', 'images/image-wrap-border-port.png')}}';
            }
            console.log(image_wrap);
            image_wrap.onload = function() {
                context.drawImage(image_wrap, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            };
            image_wrap.onerror = function() {
                console.log('errors');
            }
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('note_prev' + node_num).src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    var node_div = document.createElement('div');
    //Other non-image informantion is appended to node_div
    return node_div;
}
```

My problem is when drawing image_wrap, not image1 from my above example. Image1 from my code draws fine, but image_wrap won't appear when it is drawn to the canvas.

---

I FIXED IT!!!

I moved the creation of image_Wrap variable up with the creation of the image1 variable.

```
function processOrders(curr_order, node_num) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas' + node_num);
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

   var image1 = new Image();
   var image_wrap = new Image();
   image1.src = curr_order.image_url;
   canvas.width = image1.naturalWidth;
   canvas.height = image1.naturalHeight;
   if(image1.complete) {
       context.drawImage(image
```

I thought this wouldn't be a good idea because I didn't want to create extra variables even if they weren't going to get used, but I guess it fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to load the image using your code.

Can you confirm you are not getting an error while loading the image?

(**Seeking clarification:** *posted as an answer to demo the running code snippet*)

*Update*: added a hackish way to wait a second after loading image and before drawing it to canvas

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var image1 = new Image();

image1.src = 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/';
image1.onload = function() {
  // you could draw the image right away
  // ctx.drawImage(image1, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // OR
  // You could wait for an extra second before drawing the image (hackish, I know)
  setTimeout(function() {
    ctx.drawImage(image1, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }, 1 * 1000); // 1 second (in milliseconds)
};
```

```html
<h2>canvas</h2>
<canvas id='canvas'>
</canvas>
<hr/>
```

Comment: Thanks but it was a typo in the question. I had it written correctly in my actual code.

Comment: @nightwuffle your code should work - see my running snippet - can you replace your variable with a hard-coded URL and test it out?

Comment: The image isn't producing any errors. I substituted my URL for the one you use in your example and it still doesn't work. I'll update my post with more specific information about my code and problem.

Comment: I fixed it. I moved the declaration of the image_wrap variable up with the declaration of the image1 variable and it fixed it. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Feel free to add it as an answer for the benefit of others :)

Answer (score 2):

Set the onload function BEFORE you set the src.  It's likely that the image is loading before the onload function is being set.

```
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
context = canvas.getContext('2d');
image1 = new Image();
image1.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(image1, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
};
image1.src = '{{=URL('static', 'images/image-wrap-border-land.png')}}'; //resolves to: '/SNotes/static/images/image-wrap-border-land.png'
```

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter for context.drawImage is the image you want to draw, the second two are the position on the context....

```
context.drawImage(img,sx,sy,swidth,sheight,x,y,width,height);
```

The remaining parameters allow you to scale the image.

Suggest you try..

```
image1.onload = function() { context.drawImage(image1,0,0); }
```

Comment: Thank but I had a typo in the question. It is written correctly in my code. I have tried what you suggested, it's in my question, but it isn't working for me. I have also tried setting the image source after the onload, but it still skips over it.